# Python smtplib: bind to specific source IP address in a machine with multiple network interfaces

Tags: python, ip-address, connect, smtplib

On a host with multiple network interfaces, is it possible to bind the connect method from the Python smtplib to an specific source address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option - at least not without hacking smtplib.connect() yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This question resulted in a new feature/commit [*"smtplib: add ability to bind to specific source IP address/port"*](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/55490).

The `smtplib.SMTP` constructor got new parameter `source_address`, which you can use to specify the source IP address for the outgoing SMTP connection:

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, source_address=("127.0.0.1", 0))
```